# Column names double to character in R

Tags: r

I am trying to pivot a data frame (tbl_df) from wide to long and get the following error

Error: Can't combine  `character` and  `double`

My column names are doubles and it worked fine in the example below:

```
   dat3 <- data.frame(
    sex = c("F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT","F","F","F", "F","M","M","M", "M","TOT","TOT","TOT","TOT"),
    age = c(rep("Y70-74",12),rep("Y75-79",12)),
    geo = c("UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA", "POL","UK","GER","FRA","POL"),
    "2021W3" = c(5,3,7,5,8,2,6,5,13,5,13,10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2021W2" = c(6,8,4,5,9,1,0,4,15,9,12,9,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2021W1" = c(8,7,9,2,1,2,3,6,9, 9,12,8 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W52"= c(1,2,8,2,5,1,2,4,6, 3,10,6,   1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W51"= c(4,4,3,6,4,5,1,0,9, 5,4, 6 ,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
    "2020W50"= c(3,6,3,5,2,1,2,5,5, 7,5, 10,  1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5))


dat3
   sex    age geo X2021W3 X2021W2 X2021W1 X2020W52 X2020W51 X2020W50
1    F Y70-74  UK       5       6       8        1        4        3
2    F Y70-74 GER       3       8       7        2        4        6
3    F Y70-74 FRA       7       4       9        8        3        3
4    F Y70-74 POL       5       5       2        2        6        5
5    M Y70-74  UK       8       9       1        5        4        2
6    M Y70-74 GER       2       1       2        1        5        1
7    M Y70-74 FRA       6       0       3        2        1        2
8    M Y70-74 POL       5       4       6        4        0        5
9  TOT Y70-74  UK      13      15       9        6        9        5
10 TOT Y70-74 GER       5       9       9        3        5        7
11 TOT Y70-74 FRA      13      12      12       10        4        5
12 TOT Y70-74 POL      10       9       8        6        6       10
13   F Y75-79  UK       1       1       1        1        1        1
14   F Y75-79 GER       2       2       2        2        2        2
15   F Y75-79 FRA       3       3       3        3        3        3
16   F Y75-79 POL       4       4       4        4        4        4
17   M Y75-79  UK       1       1       1        1        1        1
18   M Y75-79 GER       1       1       1        1        1        1
19   M Y75-79 FRA       1       1       1        1        1        1
20   M Y75-79 POL       1       1       1        1        1        1
21 TOT Y75-79  UK       2       2       2        2        2        2
22 TOT Y75-79 GER       3       3       3        3        3        3
23 TOT Y75-79 FRA       4       4       4        4        4        4
24 TOT Y75-79 POL       5       5       5        5        5        5
```

I got great help on another post solving my example:

```
     names_list <- colnames(dat3[4:length(dat3)])
     
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    
     datNew <- dat3 %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = names_list, names_to = "Time") %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = c("sex","age"), )

datNew
# A tibble: 24 x 8
   geo   Time     `F_Y70-74` `M_Y70-74` `TOT_Y70-74` `F_Y75-79` `M_Y75-79`
   <chr> <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 UK    X2021W3           5          8           13          1          1
 2 UK    X2021W2           6          9           15          1          1
 3 UK    X2021W1           8          1            9          1          1
 4 UK    X2020W52          1          5            6          1          1
 5 UK    X2020W51          4          4            9          1          1
 6 UK    X2020W50          3          2            5          1          1
 7 GER   X2021W3           3          2            5          2          1
 8 GER   X2021W2           8          1            9          2          1
 9 GER   X2021W1           7          2            9          2          1
10 GER   X2020W52          2          1            3          2          1
# ... with 14 more rows, and 1 more variable: TOT_Y75-79 <dbl>
```

BUT now when I try to use it on my real data it doesn't work. As you can see in the example the columns are double as well so I really don't know why it doesn't work on my big data set

Comment: Does this work on your real data? `dat3 %>%mutate(across(names_list, as.character)) %>%pivot_longer(cols = names_list, names_to = "Time") %>%pivot_wider(names_from = c("sex","age"))`

Comment: I ran my code again and it worked which I find very strange. BUT, I have more NA's now than before which I find concerning. Also the mutate function. What does it do? Thanks for your answer